launching several telegram bots (thread/async)
I need to launch a lot of telegram bots. I can run bots in local mode on Windows or Mac.
An error occurs when running Docker
it is an open source project. It can be viewed at the link: [link] (github.com/modular-platform-it/backend/blob/develop/bot_server/…)
backend1-1  |   File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 2887, in uvloop.loop.Loop.add_signal_handler
backend1-1  | ValueError: add_signal_handler() can only be called from the main thread


Code:
 class BaseTelegramBot:
    """Основа телеграмм Бота"""

    def __init__(self, bot_data):
        super().__init__()
     self.bot = Bot(token=self.token)
     self.dispatcher = Dispatcher()

bot = BaseTelegramBot(bot_data=bot_data)
asyncio.run(bot.start())  

async def start(self):
        py_logger.info(f"Бот стартовал {self.bot_data.id}")
        await self.bot.set_my_commands(commands=self.commands)
        await self.dispatcher.start_polling(self.bot)

I don't understand why this is such a problem in Docker. HELP! How to run bots in thread mode

the Docker container probably manages its own event loop which prevents asyncio or threading (which is what the code does) from working.

Yes, I understand something like this, but I don’t understand what to do with it

In Python, signal handling is restricted to the main thread.  When you're running a Python application inside a Docker container, this behavior doesn't change. If your application is multi-threaded and you're trying to set up a signal handler in a thread that is not the main thread, you'll encounter this error.

i believe the solution is to add the code to the main thread.  I have not used docker, but experience the same issue with a jupyter notebook which behaves in a similar way...

I know that you can attach processes to the mainloop.  with the asyncio module it is like this loop = asyncio.get_running_loop(), so there must be similar for threading...

Unfortunately, I need it in docker. I already regretted it

the example code is a bit wierd, because it uses both threading and asyncio.  Usually, it is one or the other... but not both !!!

Initially it was like this, and then I started experimenting  @app.get("/{bot_id}/start/") def start_bot(bot_id):     bot_data = (         connection.session.query(TelegramBot).filter(TelegramBot.id == bot_id).first()     )     bot = BaseTelegramBot(bot_data=bot_data)      asyncio.run(bot.start())  

it is an open source project. It can be viewed at the link: [link] (https://github.com/modular-platform-it/backend/blob/develop/bot_server/api.py)

the example given in the link uses asyncio only and not threading.

Yes, I wrote this part of the code. And I got the same error with the main thread. Without docker everything starts
